# issue with cy.scrollTo('bottom')

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of the page using the cy.scrollTo('bottom') command but getting the following error-

**"cy.scrollTo() failed because this element is not scrollable: *<*window*>*"**

I've tried cy.window.scrollTo('bottom')  but this is also throwing the same error.

Could you please help? and what's actually meant by 'scrollable'?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can use this `cy.scrollTo` or `.scrollIntoView` and you can learn that by watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHn7647xOz8&ab_channel=glebbahmutov)